Distance of convex hull of orthogonal points on a sphere to the center of the sphere
Suppose that we have a d-dimensional unit sphere centered at the origin (I use d to denote the space the sphere lives in, so a 2-dimensional sphere is a circle in 2-dimensional space). My goal is to find the distance of the origin from the convex hull of n orthogonal points along the sphere, where $n \leq d$. I am not too familiar with convex hulls, so I have been approaching this using elementary geometry. I only have basic results when n=2 or n=3 so far:
If $n=2$ and $d=2$, the distance is $\sqrt{2} / 2$. Here, the convex hull is simply a line connecting the two points, which is the hypotenuse of a right triangle where the vertices are the two points and the origin. Using a simple geometric argument, the minimal distance from the origin to this line is the line that bisects the hypotenuse, which is calculated to be $\sqrt{2} / 2$.
If $n=3$ and $d=3$, the distance is $1/\sqrt{3}$. Here the convex hull is an equilateral triangle, with side length $\sqrt{2}$. I'm pretty sure that the minimal line is from the origin to the centroid of the convex hull, which I calculated to be $1/\sqrt{3}$.
I also think that as long as $n \leq d$, the distance depends only on n, so the above results hold for any $d > n$. My intuition comes from looking at $n=2$ and $d=3$, which will yield the same kind of right triangle argument.
Does anyone know how I might approach generalizing these results to higher dimensions? Also, do you have any pointers to things to learn that might help me solve this problem? Thank you.

The distance between the origin and the convex hull of the points is the minimum distance of all of the points of the convex hull to the origin.
Let $x$ be a convex combination of the orthogonal points $x_1,\ldots,x_n.$
$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i x_i\;\;\;,\;\;\;
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i = 1 \;\;\;\text{and} \;\;\;
\lambda_i\geq 0 \;\, \text{for} \;\, i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}
$$
Due to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$
\left\langle
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
,
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rangle
\;
\leq
\;
\left\|
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\|
\;\cdot\;
\left\|
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n
\end{pmatrix}
\right\|
$$
which means
$$
1\;\leq \;\sqrt{n} \; \cdot \; \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2}
\;\;\;\text{or}\;\;\;
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2} \; \geq \; \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
The distance of $x$ to the origin is
$$
\|x\| = \left\|
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i x_i
\right\| 
= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_i\lambda_j \langle x_i,x_j\rangle}
= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2} \; \geq \; \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
So the distance is at least $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$. It is easy to see that this value is taken if $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \ldots = \lambda_n = \frac{1}{n}.$
Therefore, the distance of the convex hull to the origin is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}},$ and the point of the convex hull that has this exact distance to the origin is the arithmetic mean of the orthogonal points.
Note: The inequality $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^2\geq\frac{1}{n}$ can be obtained without the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as follows:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i^2 
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\left(\lambda_i-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \\
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\lambda_i-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2
  +2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\lambda_i-\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n}
   +\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \\
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\lambda_i-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2
  +\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n} \\
= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\lambda_i-\frac{1}{n}\right)^2+\frac{1}{n}
\geq\frac{1}{n}
$$

Thank you so much for the thorough and insightful response!
